# opencv assertion failed (matrix.cpp line 508)

Tags: c++, opencv

I have used visual studio 2015 express to compile a program which can be successfully run in my first computer. Then I tried to move the dll files needed to run the program and the exe file generated by vs to another computer which didnt install vs 2015 and opencv library.

However, the program can only be run in the half way and will have error shown in the below picture when doing opencv functions declared inside the program.

What's wrong with the program? Would you mind giving me any suggestion to fix it?

Thanks!!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9_vlz2OS7h9Q1JTSHQ1MUVQazg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (or more) of those conditions in the assert statement is returning false.  Suggest commenting them out one by one and see which one is causing the problem.
You could also just remove the assert statement (typical when in production) and test the program's behavior.

Comment: But I didnt install VS 2015 in the second PC so I couldnt comment the statements one by one. I would like to confirm if only the exe file and DLLs are needed for a completely new computer to run successfully ? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just found the error comes from bad argument I have put when I was using BAT file to call that exe file. Thanks! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem should not be the missing vs 2015.

It looks like an exception thrown by the constructor of the Region of interest (cv::roi i think?). You are trying to create a roi that is either bigger then the original image or you are trying to make a roi with negativ with or height.